# React-phone-input-2: Autofocus not working after selecting a country code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, focus, react-phone-input-2

Can you explain, how can I focus the input after selecting the code country? On the demo it works as expected, but mine doesn't work...

There is a code of PhoneInput component:

```
<PhoneInput
   inputProps={{
       autoFocus: true
   }}
   onChange={(e, action) => phoneChange(e, action)}
   localization={i18n.language === 'ru' && ru}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   value={phoneNumber}
   buttonClass={styles.phoneButton}
   inputClass={styles.phoneInput}
   dropdownClass={styles.phoneDropdown}
   searchClass={styles.phoneSearch}
   searchPlaceholder={searchHolder}
   searchNotFound={searchFind}
   country={country}
   disableSearchIcon={true}
   enableSearch={true}
   autocompleteSearch={true}
   jumpCursorToEnd={true}
/>
```

I have tried to pass inputProps to a PhoneInput component, but it focuses the input on the first mount ;(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the most recent version of react-phone-input-2 installed on your project (`2.15.1` or `2.15.0`).

Versions lower than `2.14.0` will do the work for you.

You can uninstall your current version:

```
npm uninstall react-phone-input-2
```

And install the `2.14.0` version, that works with `autoFocus`, when you change the country:

```
npm install react-phone-input-2@2.14.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).